# make jwt encode faster

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I have a `/token` endpoint that is working with a `password` grant. Because it's encoding a `JWT` token, it has high latency of about 1 second. Is there a way to make signing the JWT faster?

I'm using Go with the `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` library.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rsa"
    "git.snappfood.ir/golang/framework/assert"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"

    
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

var (
    private *rsa.PrivateKey
    public  *rsa.PublicKey
)

func main() {
    var err error
    var priv, pub []byte
    pub, err = ioutil.ReadFile("public.pem")
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    priv, err = ioutil.ReadFile("private.pem")
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    public, err = jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(pub)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    private, err = jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM(priv)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "jti": "dara",
        "scopes": func() []string {
            return []string{"sara", "dara"}
        }(),
        "aud": "aud",
        "sub": "",
    }
    cl := jwt.MapClaims{}

    for k, v := range data {
        cl[k] = v
    }
    cl["iat"] = time.Now().Add(-6 * time.Hour).Unix()
    cl["exp"] = time.Now().UTC().Add(1 * time.Hour).Unix()

    t := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.GetSigningMethod("RS256"), cl)

    t2 := time.Now()
    tokenString, err := t.SignedString(private)
    assert.Nil(err)
    logrus.Warn(time.Since(t2))
    logrus.Warn(tokenString)

}
```

Comment: SignedString boils down to a call to [rsa.SignPKCS1v15](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#SignPKCS1v15) in your case. The timing semantics of this function are controlled by its `rand.Reader` -- its (first) argument. In the case of `jwt-go`, this is [`crypto/rand.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#pkg-variables).

The implementation of `crypto/rand.Reader` depends on your platform. It may be blocking for a long time because of low entropy on your system. Try measuring across platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your description @thwd . I'm using Ubuntu server and I want to reduce the time for encoding , how can I increase the entropy ? or is there another way ?

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion that it was the JWT generation that took 1 second? That sounds very unlikely to me. Did you see in profiling that the JWT encoding is what takes the most of time?

Comment: I cant tell why it takes 1 second which is really slow. I am also signing JWTs in a project and there is no measurable impact. As a hint your used library `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` is archived and no longer maintend. I would suggest switching to [https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt) even though this might not affect your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Without jumping into library details, it's small but you don't need to initialize a `map[string]interface` then loop over it to populate a `jwt.MapClaims{}`. You can just start with a `jwt.MapClaims{}` like this:

```
cl := jwt.MapClaims{
    "jti": "dara",
    "scopes": func() []string {
        return []string{"sara", "dara"}
    }(),
    "aud": "aud",
    "sub": "",
    // no need to do these separately:
    "iat": time.Now().Add(-6 * time.Hour).Unix(),
    "exp": time.Now().UTC().Add(1 * time.Hour).Unix(),
}
```

---

Consider using [Benchmark Tests](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks) to experiment with different approaches.

---

**EDIT**:

I think `time.Now()` can be slow sometimes depending on the machine/os and can be a possible factor. So make sure to benchmark `time.Now()` and look for issues such as [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57749) if you want to dig deeper

Answer (score -2):

In Golang you can always step down to C level. But with that comes a large increase of complexity of shipping your app. But if any ms counts for you, it might be the way out.

But at the same time, (I have not profiled anything) it is still Go. You could easily parallelise the private/public ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM calls to shave a few ms off